# Remove characters between a special character and a word

Tags: linux, sed, filenames

I have doing tons of research and can't seem to figure it out.

I am using sed and trying to process a file of paths

/path/to/somewhere/for-something.rar

I need to remove everything past the last / but not the / itself. Can anyone help me with this? I can never handle sed lol

Comment: It looks like you want to do something that `dirname` command do. Can you try this one?

Comment: Every line is different. I have a find command that searches for .rar files and another that extracts them. But I need it to show only the folder name for the command to work properly

Comment: That's exactly what `dirname` do. But to be sure, could you provide examples of input and output?

Comment: Could you say something about the underlying issue in your question, e.g. why you have a file with pathnames in it and whether this is part of solving -_another_ task? Storing pathnames in a file is rarely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dirname`:

```
path=/path/to/somewhere/for-something.rar
dir="$(dirname $path)/"
```

Or use shell:

```
dir="${path%\/*}/"
```

Output:

```
$ echo "$dir"
/path/to/somewhere/
```

Answer (score 0):

To find all "/..../file.rar"  and print "/..../" in a file-of-paths you can use good old grep...

```
grep -Po '/\S+/(?=\S+\.rar\b)' file-of-paths
```